# Can't Import Python Class

Tags: python, python-import, nameerror

I am having an issue with Python imports. I created a module to conveniently import a few classes inside of the module with a single statement. I put all of my imports inside of the init of that module, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
maindir\
- driver.py
- Utility\
  - __init__.py
  - UtilityClasses.py
```

My folder structure looks like the above.
Inside of UtilityClasses I have one a class that I have created called MyClass.

Inside of the init file in the Utility folder, I have code that says:

```
import UtilityClasses
from UtilityClasses import MyClass
```

Inside of driver.py I have code that says:

```
import Utility
myVar = MyClass(param1)
```

However, when I run this, I get an error telling me that name MyClass is not defined.

Comment: why not just use `from Utility.UtilityClasses import MyClass`? in driver.py

Comment: there are a bunch of UtilitiyClasses and functions that I want to use throughout the project, and was hoping to do **import Utility** as a convenient shorthand so the top of the driver (and other) files isn't full of includes

Comment: Import everything using `*`, see my answer.

Comment: It may be worth breaking those out into different utility concerns.  You don't want to have a single class responsible for everything as it'll make it harder to read as you continue along.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `__init__.py`, you can do

```
from UtilityClasses import *
from SomeOtherFile import *
```

This will import everything from `UtilityClasses.py` and `SomeOtherFile.py`.

<del>But you still have to access it using the module name</del>

Update: You can access everything like this

In `driver.py`:

```
from Utility import *

a = MyClass()
b = ClassInSomeOtherFile()
```

Comment: Sweet that worked. Any idea why my approach didn't work? Isn't the point of that __init__ to allow me to list exactly what I want to import. For example, what if I only want to import a specific list of classes that I specify in the __init__ (so that I don't have to do *)

Comment: I.e. Does my import in _ _ init _ _ have no use?

Comment: The classes will be imported in init, but in drivers, you are importing init itself, so you still have to do init.myclass to access those classes. With this approach, you are import everything inside init, so you can access it directly.

Answer (score 3):

Your code

```
import Utility
myVar = MyClass(param1)
```

of course won't work -- `MyClass` is nowhere mentioned and it won't come magically from nowhere.  Explicit is better than implicit:

```
from Utility import MyClass
myVar = MyClass(param1)
```

should work like a charm!

Comment: But I mention it in the init of the Utility module, which I import at the top of Driver.py -- my goal is not to have to name MyClass, but to use Utility's init file to do the import of everything in UtilityClasses...

Comment: @Eugene, that's not in scope and so of course won't inject barenames elsewhere!  **No way** `import Utility` will EVER pollute the importing namespace with other barenames -- that's just **NOT** Python!  (And a big part of why I love Python and have structured my career and my whole life so much around it: **explicit is better than implicit**).  If you're keen for black-magic "action at a distance" languages with namespaces mysteriously polluted with barenames never explicitly called in, use just about **any** language BUT Python, and may the wind be at your back!

Comment: ha ok - thanks :) wasn't commenting on relative value of either approach, just trying to understand the logic, but I believe thanks to kedar above and your answer, i get it now